# Writing some data into DB when leaving the page

Tags: jquery

I want to write some data into a SQL-DB when the user closes or leave the page. Is this possible?

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    if ($('#target').length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/script.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { 'anthing': 'write' },
            dataType: "json"
        });
        alert('leave it');
    }
});
```

This attempt doesn't work...

Comment: the code is correct..just check if control is coming inside if statement or not.

Comment: Depending on how you close the page it may not run in time.

Comment: all that handler can do is return a string for the user to be displayed

Comment: @DavidFregoli: So is there another method to do that?